# Why is gmail not responding to media-queries?

Tags: html, gmail, media-queries, html-email, responsive

What's good StackOverflow? I've been trying to figure out for the longest while now why Gmail isn't picking up on my HTML Email's Media Query. It looks good with wide screen but Gmail isn't responding to my phone's screen width, so on phone looks weird and buggy.

I've already tried looking through similar questions, and even tried re-writing my CSS to the point to where I re-wrote my CSS several times to see if the media query would pick up even the smallest of change.

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width ,initial-scale=1" />
  <style type="text/css">
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Libre+Baskerville');

    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 15px;
    }

    .center {
      text-align: center;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .wrapper {
      width: 100%;
      table-layout: fixed;
    }

    .inner-wrapper {
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 670px;
      background: #554348;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }

    table {
      border-spacing: 0;
      font-family: sans-serif;
      color: #727f80;
    }

    .header-table {
      text-align: center;
      padding: 10px 0px 0 0;
    }

    .header-table .header {
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 610px;
      display: inline-block;
      background: #fff;
      border-top: 2px solid #E5C2C0;
      border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
      padding-bottom: 24px;
    }

    .header-table img {
      width: 75px;
      float: left;
      border: 2px solid #E5C2C0;
      border-radius: 6px 0 0 0;
      border-top: none;
    }

    .slogan {
      color: #000;
      font-size: 12px;
      margin-top: 124px;
      color: #7FC29B;
    }

    .slogan-hr {
      width: 25vh;
    }

    .outer-table {
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 670px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .outer-table img {
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 670px;
      height: auto;
    }

    td {
      padding: 0;
    }

    p {
      margin: 0;
    }

    a {
      color: #f1f1f1;
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    .main-table {
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 610px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      border-radius: 6px;
      margin-top: 25px;
      margin-bottom: 25px;
      background: #fff;
    }

    .three-column {
      width: 100%;
    }

    .three-column img {
      width: 120px;
    }

    .section {
      /* Change display to inline-block on mobile */
      width: 100%;
      display: inline-flex;
      margin-top: 15px;
      margin-left: 30px;
    }

    .section .pic-container {
      display: inline-block;
    }

    .section .desc-container {
      margin: auto;
    }

    .desc-container td {
      padding-bottom: 25px;
    }

    .desc-container .content {
      margin-top: 32px;
    }

    .desc-table p {
      margin-top: 5px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    .desc-table .h3 {
      font-weight: bold;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      color: #424B54;
    }

    .desc-table .price {
      font-size: 20px;
      font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', serif;
      color: #7FC29B;
    }

    .button-container {
      margin-right: 90px;
      margin-top: 65px;
      height: 35px;
    }

    .btn-holder {
      font-size: 25px;
      padding: 9px;
      border-radius: 25px;
      color: #fff;
      background: #4C4B63;
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    .outer-table-2 {
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 670px !important;
      background: #fff;
      border-top: 3px solid #D4F5F5;
      border-bottom: 3px solid #D4F5F5;
    }

    .call-to-action {
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 670px;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .cta-text {
      font-size: 24px;
      margin-top: 30px;
      margin-bottom: 30px;
      color: #4C4B63;
    }

    .cta-button {
      margin-top: 30px;
      margin-bottom: 30px;
    }

    .outer-table-3 {
      margin-top: 30px;
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 670px;
      background: #4C4B63;
      border-top: 2px solid #7FC29B;
      border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
    }

    .footer-table {
      width: 100%;
      margin-top: 32px;
    }

    .footer-header-table {
      width: 100%;
    }

    .footer-header {
      color: #fff;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .footer-header .heart {
      color: red;
    }

    .footer-logo-table {
      float: left;
    }

    .footer-logo {
      width: 67px;
    }

    .footer-social-table {
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .social-list {
      display: inline-flex;
      list-style: none;
    }

    .social-list li {
      margin-left: 10px;
      margin-right: 10px;
    }

    .social-list img {
      width: 55px;
    }

    .footer-text-table {
      float: right;
      text-align: right;
      margin-top: 25px;
    }

    .footer {
      font-size: 12px;
      color: #fff;
    }

    .footer a {
      text-transform: uppercase;
      color: red;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width:360px) {
      .cta-button .btn-holder {
        font-size: 18px !important;
      }

      .footer-social-table {
        width: 100%;
      }

      .social-list img {
        width: 50px;
      }
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width:768px) {
      .wrapper {
        overflow: hidden;
      }

      .section {
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0;
        margin-top: 15px;
        text-align: center;
      }

      .pic .content {
        width: 100%;
      }

      .section .home {
        width: 65%;
      }



      .desc-container {
        width: 100%;
      }

      .desc-table {
        margin: 0 auto;
      }

      .desc-table .h3 {
        font-size: 20px;
      }

      .desc-table .price {
        font-size: 24px;
      }

      .size {
        font-size: 20px;
      }

      .section .button-container {
        margin-top: 25px;
        margin-bottom: 25px;
        width: 100%;
      }

      .button-container .button-table {
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding-bottom: 25px;
      }

      .outer-table-2 {
        width: 100%;
      }

      .cta-button .btn-holder {
        font-size: 23px;
      }

      .outer-table-3 {
        width: 100%;
      }

      .footer-social-table {
        width: 100%;
      }

      .social-list {
        padding: 0;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>
```

I figured it was because it was because the @media screen and it had to be either "@media only screen" or "@media (){..." but none of those did anything.

What I expected (running on web browser) vs what actually happens (gmail app)
[image]

Here's a link to the whole code:
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b0em2sLg/)

Even if you can't help, thank you for reading.

**UPDATE!!!**
Thanks to Digital_Frankenstein, I was able to fix the problem. What I should've done was add some `!important` tags on my CSS, and specifically on the media queries. For future HTML Email Devs, don't forget this. Because this is really important.

Comment: Okay, so I made a simpler version to test if Gmail is able to use media queries

`<style type="text/css">
      div[class="wrapper"]{background: red; height: 120px;}
      @media (max-width:1080px) {
        div[class="wrapper"]{background:blue;}
      }
    </style>`

And it's still not working....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

took me a while to debug this, taking section by section out.
I hate default styles in the head. Makes it so much harder to debug, but each to their own and I know a lot of people are shifting to that method because of the Gmail update.

To resolve your issues in Gmail:

1. You need to add !important to all media query CSS, to override default styling.
2. Your slogan-hr was pushing everything out because of it's vh base width. In your media query I added an override of width:90%!important;.
3. You need to reduce the font size of your last button. It's blowing out at 23px in Gmail. I would suggest 20px maybe?
4. Your footer doesn't look too great. Best if you fiddle with that further, as both items sitting right up against the edges doesn't look great.

Finally, I would suggest avoiding this technique if you aren't completely confident with it.
I personally don't see the worth in it, since Gmail started rendering responsive code, but I know some devs use it for the outlier mobile email clients and that makes sense.
But I stick with old school tables since it just works and my clients will be managing the templates. 
If I were always available to update and manage the templates I build, then it makes sense.
Just some food for thought. Hope this resolves your issues :)

Comment: I added the `!important` and it worked! I also took your design advice and put the bottom logo and the footer text to touch the bottom of the footer area. Thank you so much! You don't know how much stress you saved me from.

Comment: Is there something I can read or watch so I can learn about the old school method?

Comment: Gmail clips email if it's more than, i think, 120kb. So be careful regarding size of your email. Good to minify.

Comment: @KuyaDanny Nicole Merline wrote this last year - https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/build-an-html-email-template-from-scratch--webdesign-12770

Otherwise Litmus has this old infographic that could be helpful - https://litmus.com/blog/html-email-coding-101-infographic

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In My case, actually I was using the other syntax which was working fine in other place but not in gmail so if you are using this syntax

```
  @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {

        table[class="w320"] {
            width: 320px !important;
        }
```

This works fine in all other places but not in gmail app, so for that use the better syntax:

```
     @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
        table.w320{
            width: 320px !important;
        }
        }
```